# how to remove css style when inactive

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am trying to make login form and I want to only one div border to change color at a time. When I clicked on another div previous border did not return back to grey.

In this picture both the input tag changes their color when clicked on both:

[image: show this image]

```
let emailbox = document.getElementById("email");
let namebox = document.getElementById("name");

let colorChange = (e) => {
  if (e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.border === "1px solid rgb(36, 45, 52)") {
    e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.border = "2px solid rgb(29, 161, 242)"
  } else {
    e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.border = "1px solid rgb(36, 45, 52)"
  }
};

namebox.addEventListener("click", colorChange);
emailbox.addEventListener("click", colorChange);
```

Comment: Don't use the DOM to store the state of your app. Store a reference to the active element in a variable instead.

Comment: Yes, your logic should not depend on specific styling. What if that changes via CSS? Move your styles to classes and use state variables to track them.

Comment: Why don't you use simply CSS-only and the `:focus` pseudo attribute?

Comment: i nested input element inside div that's why didn't use pseudo attribute. div contains <label> and <input> and i want to apply border when active and remove it when i comes out of the element

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan thank you very much it worked <3.......